# Multiplication and exponentiation in assembly

Tags: assembly, linked-list

I need to support those operations in assembly, as the numbers represented by lists with no limited size. Each link contains data and next fields, as the data is two hexadecimal digits. 
I cannot change the representation of the numbers, I need to find a way to do so.
[Link to the question on stack exchange(I've been told that this topic is more relevant here).](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/42345/multiplication-and-exponentiation-algorithms)

Any help would be great.

Comment: What platform/architecture? Most have a multiply instruction of some sort, and you can use [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Comment: "two hexadecimal digits", so a byte, right? Or is it actually a string of two characters?

Comment: I am writing in assembly 32 bit. I know that there are saved instructions, but the situation here is different. I can have two numbers represented by a lists of length 10... I cannot use the ordinary 'mult' operation.

Comment: Sure you can, you just need some extra stuff too. You know how long multiplication is done by hand, it's not that different on a computer - different base usually (base 256 here)

Comment: Harold - yes, each data field is of size byte, and contains 2 hexa digits (real value, not string or char).

Comment: @user3680924 from the comments I think you are confused about "two hexadecimal digits in one byte". That's just a byte. Whether it holds 8 binary digits (bits) or 2 hexadecimal digits depends solely on the way you want to represent it.